# Converting geographic coordinate "DMS" string to float using C#

Tags: c#, gps, geocoding

I have geographical coordinates in DMS format and I want to convert it into corresponding decimal/float value. An example is -33° 51' 21.91" how do I convert it into decimal value? Is there any library available or .Net provide inbuilt function for this?

Comment: Does this help@  http://stackoverflow.com/a/28640937/847962

Comment: What value do you want as a result exactly? BTW, asking off-site resources and libraries are off topic here.

Comment: @jason.kaisersmith-a small tweek and that worked. Thanks.