# how to convert GIS DMS coordinates

Tags: node.js, asp.net-core, gis

I know this is a very wide subject - still - I would like to convert a **GIS DMS coordinates**, for example:

> 33° 0' 10'' , 33° 40' 30''

into an **EPSG:3857** format, ie:

> 3689865.02422557637, 3212878.5986975324

(this is not the calcualated convert, just an exmaple of the formats).

I know there are calculations\conversions in Map suppliers (**ESRI**, etc.). I'm looking for either of these ways, if somehow possible:

1. nodejs module (proj4js ? I looked in it but couldn't find a way doing so).
2. asp.net core FW feature\nuget ?

Answer (score 1):

Yeah, proj4js can do this. First [convert your DMS coordinates into decimal degrees](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3249700/convert-degrees-minutes-seconds-to-decimal-coordinates), then tell proj4js to convert from WGS-84 to EPSG:3857.

Happily, [proj4js ships with this conversion](http://proj4js.org/#named-projections), so you don't have to look for the datum strings online.

```
const proj4= require("proj4");
// TODO: that's not the correct conversion of the original DMS to decimal degrees :)
console.log(proj4("WGS84", "EPSG:3857", [33.01, 33.4]));
```

outputs

```
[ 3674656.3910859604, 3948518.4270993923 ]
```